# Creating a simple table with Lua tables C API

Tags: c, api, lua

I'm running a MySQL query which always returns 4 rows:

`row->name`, `row->date`, `row->ip`, `row->custom`

What I want to achieve is create a simple table basing on the above results so it would look like:

```
{
     "name" = result of row->name,
     "date" = result of row->date,
     "ip"   = result of row->ip,
     "custom" = result of row->custom
}
```

I have tried multiple possibilities, but the examples posted are really varied and I got a problems making it working.

My last unsuccessful try:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 4);
top = lua_gettop(L);
lua_pushstring(L, "name");
lua_pushstring(L, row->name);
lua_pushstring(L, "date");
lua_pushnumber(L, row->date);
lua_pushstring(L, "ip");
lua_pushstring(L, row->ip);
lua_pushstring(L, "custom");
lua_pushstring(L, row->custom);
lua_settable(L, top);
```

Comment: [`lua_settable()`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_settable) sets **only  1 value** and pops **only 1 pair of key, value** from stack. Repeat it 4.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, [`lua_settable()`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_settable) takes care only of one `key, value` pair. Must repeat that if You need more.

I'd prefer saving the Lua stack space like this:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 4);

lua_pushstring(L, "name");
lua_pushstring(L, row->name);
lua_settable(L, -3);  /* 3rd element from the stack top */

lua_pushstring(L, "date");
lua_pushstring(L, row->date);
lua_settable(L, -3);

lua_pushstring(L, "ip");
lua_pushstring(L, row->ip);
lua_settable(L, -3);

lua_pushstring(L, "custom");
lua_pushstring(L, row->custom);
lua_settable(L, -3);

/* We still have table left on top of the Lua stack. */
```

Also, You could write some kind of C struct iterator or something.

NOTE: if this is for some kind of Lua wrapper - You should ensure [standardized way of doing that](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_CFunction). In the following example applied [@lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) comment about shortening it a bit:

```
int 
l_row_push(lua_State *l)
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 4); /* creates and pushes new table on top of Lua stack */

    lua_pushstring(L, row->name); /* Pushes table value on top of Lua stack */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "name");  /* table["name"] = row->name. Pops key value */

    lua_pushstring(L, row->date);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "date");

    lua_pushstring(L, row->ip);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "ip");

    lua_pushstring(L, row->custom);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "custom");

    /* Returning one table which is already on top of Lua stack. */
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: Fixes usage of [`lua_setfield()`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_setfield) by [@lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) note. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas yeah, it might look tricky at the beginning.  Overall - it's not that bad at all.

Comment: Can I use the `lua_newtable` instead of the `lua_createtable` ?

Comment: @Lucas definitely. `lua_createtable()` saves some time of increasing memory allocated for the table each time inserting stuff. And recommended to be used. If size of table is not known, You're free to use `lua_newtable`.

Comment: The code is compiling itself, but in Lua when I do `print(variable["name"]);` nothing is being printed.

Comment: And yes, I am using a wrapper, did that like on your example so you could know how its looks like: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WQVugBz7

Comment: Nevermind, return `1` worked for it, just seen that its not going to return 4 tables, lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lucas could You show fuller example of what You're trying to do, please? Are You using `lightuserdata` to pass values from `Lua state machine`?

Comment: `lua_setfield` receives the key not the value.

Comment: @lhf Fixed. Thank You very much for noticing!